# Create Excel Consolidated Worksheet with multiple sources in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to Consolidate multiple Worksheets on one Worksheet using VBA. How do I tell VBA to only consolidate the worksheets that are visible?

Comment: Are you looking for worksheet property `Visible` which has values `xlSheetVisible`, `xlSheetHidden` and `xlSheetVeryHidden`?

Comment: I can identify the visible Worksheets. The main problem that I am having is to be able to add multiple worksheets in the Array when using the Consolidating Function in VBA.

Comment: You really should include the code that you have to get a better answer, but I've never used `Consolidate` before, so you piqued my curiosity. I'll try to answer soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took Jerry Sullivan's answer from http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/620641-using-visual-basic-applications-perform-consolidate-function.html and tweaked it. The MSDN site was of some help in understanding the arguments, for example that the array of ranges must contain fully qualified addresses in R1C1 style.

Of course you gave no details on how you are trying to use `Consolidate` so this answer is generic. It consolidates the used range from all visible sheets in the active workbook using the Sum function:

```
Sub Consolidate_Totals()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sArray As Variant, i As Integer
    ReDim sArray(1 To 1)

    '---Make Array with Named Ranges to be Consolidated
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Visible And ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
            i = i + 1
            ReDim Preserve sArray(1 To i)
            sArray(i) = ws.UsedRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1, external:=True)
        End If
    Next ws
    If i = 0 Then Exit Sub

    '---Consolidate using the Array
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Consolidate Sources:=(sArray), _
        Function:=xlSum, TopRow:=False, LeftColumn:=False, CreateLinks:=False
End Sub
```