# Consolidation by Sum from Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, consolidation

I have been having a difficulty with the final stage of code for consolidating data by sum from an array of worksheets (dynamically created).

The code returns an error 1004: *Consolidate method of Range class failed*

Probably, I am setting the array entries to unsupported values (is R1C1 reference style necessary, for example)? Please help.

*P.S. I can probably go with one cycle only to populate array, I shall try figure this out later.*

Thanks to guys previously contributing to similar requests:

[Create Excel Consolidated Worksheet with multiple sources in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39425571/create-excel-consolidated-worksheet-with-multiple-sources-in-vba?rq=1)

[adding values to variable array VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663879/adding-values-to-variable-array-vba)

Here is the code:

```
Sub Consolidate_ALL_Click_2()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wArr, siArr As Variant
ReDim siArr(0 To 0)

'--- Run through all sheets in workbook
For Each ws In Worksheets 
  For Each wArr In Array("A", "B", "C", "D")
'--- Check if worksheet name is in matching the list
    If ws.Name = wArr Then
       ReDim Preserve siArr(UBound(siArr) + 1)
'--- Write address to array
       siArr(UBound(siArr)) = ws.Range("A10:C300").Address(ReferenceStyle:=XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, external:=True)
    End If
  Next wArr
Next ws

'--- Consolidate, using pre-defined array of Ranges        
Worksheets("SUMMARY").Range("A10").Consolidate Sources:=Array(siArr), _
Function:=xlSum, TopRow:=False, LeftColumn:=False, CreateLinks:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manner in which you are creating `siArr` ensures that `siArr(0) will always be empty.  Hence the`Consolidate` method will fail on the empty item.

**Edit:** Looking at another issue, you do, indeed, need to use the `R1C1` reference style as stated in `HELP` for that topic.

If you are going to use the `ReDim Preserve` method, then try:

```
'--- Run through all sheets in workbook
For Each ws In Worksheets
  For Each wArr In Array("A", "B", "C", "D")
'--- Check if worksheet name is in matching the list
    If ws.Name = wArr Then
        If Not IsEmpty(siArr(UBound(siArr))) Then _
       ReDim Preserve siArr(UBound(siArr) + 1)
'--- Write address to array
       siArr(UBound(siArr)) = ws.Range("A10:C300").Address(ReferenceStyle:=XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1, external:=True)
    End If
  Next wArr
Next ws
```

*I usually use the Dictionary or Collection object to collect a list of objects/variables of unknown size; and then reDim my array just once when done, avoiding `ReDim Preserve` completely. Your referenced method will leave an empty element at the end of the array.  Your method here leaves an empty element at the beginning of the array. Both are avoided by using a Dictionary or Collection object*

So you could use instead:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wArr, siArr As Variant
Dim cWS As Collection

Set cWS = New Collection
'--- Run through all sheets in workbook
For Each ws In Worksheets
  For Each wArr In Array("A", "B", "C", "D")
'--- Check if worksheet name is in matching the list
    If ws.Name = wArr Then
'--- Add address to collection
       cWS.Add ws.Range("A10:C300").Address(ReferenceStyle:=XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1, external:=True)
    End If
  Next wArr
Next ws

'--- write addresses to array
Dim I As Long
ReDim siArr(0 To cWS.Count - 1)
For Each wArr In cWS
    siArr(I) = wArr
    I = I + 1
Next wArr
```

Comment: Thank you! Your method works. I am using multiple collections from different ranges in the same macro now. The consolidation part in this case looks bulky. But i guess, you have to go with it. Thank you once again!